# How to read the content of a CSV and export it in a constant using React?

Tags: reactjs, csv, papaparse

Here is my Products.js file:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Papa from 'papaparse';

import csvFile from './products.csv'

  let records = [];

  Papa.parse(csvFile, {
    header: true,
    download: true,
    complete: function (input) {
      records = input.data;
      console.log(records);      
    },    
  });
  
export const products= records

export const products1=[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "name 1",
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "name2",
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "name3",
  }, 
]
```

and it is imported from this SampleData.js file :

```
import React from 'react';
import { products } from '../data/Products'
import { filters } from '../data/Filters'
import { brands } from '../data/Brands'


export default function withSampleData(WrappedComponent) {
    class HOC extends React.Component {

        render() {
            return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} products={products} filters={filters} brands={brands} />
        }
    }
    return HOC;
}
```

In the Products.js file, the dummy data (products1) works well when renaming it to product. But the one I need (products = records) ends up being empty. the log inside the Papa parse function shows a full array of objects though.

I suspect that there are some async issues, but I do not know how to fix that.

the products.csv file is stored locally.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try your content read logic like below

```js
const parseCSV = async (csvFile: string, size: number) => {
    const data = [];
    const errors = [];
    const meta = [];
    let count = 0;

    Papa.parse(csvFile, {
      complete: async () => {
        // if you want you can validate file content here 
        
        console.log(data);
       
      },
      header: true,
      download: true,
      skipEmptyLines: true,
      step: (row) => {
        data.push({ id: count, ...row.data });
        count++;
      },
    });
  };
```

Comment: I tried but it does't change anything